# Bread question regarding malt

Tags: bread

I'm looking at a bread recipe that doesn't have any diastatic malt powder in it, but does have a small amount of regular malt syrup. I'm going to add some diastatic malt powder to the recipe, so I was wondering if that should replace the malt syrup or should I just leave it in and have both?

Comment: That depends on what you're trying to accomplish with your modifications. Why are you adding diastatic malt powder, and why are you using a recipe that doesn't include diastatic malt powder?

Comment: I'm using it because I feel like my starter isn't as good as it should be (I might be wrong,) and apparently the diastatic malt powder is like a super feeder for yeast and I get better results with it so far using this starter. I'm just not sure if the if the malt syrup in this recipe is just there for flavour, or if it serves the same purpose as the diastatic malt powder.

Comment: This isn't quite a full answer, but King Arthur Flour writes of diastatic malt powder: "Especially useful when flour does not have barley malt added."  Seems to suggest that there may not be much purpose in adding two kinds of malt.

Comment: Good enough for me, I'll leave it out. Thank you!

Comment: All bread flours that I know of have been adjusted at the mill with diastatic malt. It may be listed on the side of the bag like "1/10 % barley malt added". Malt syrup just acts as a sugar substitute, not providing the same results as diaststic malt. Adding diastatic malt is best done at the mill, where they have the experience and equipment to measure the results.

Answer (score 2):

Two different substances here. 
*Non-diastatic* malt powder is mostly used for flavor.
*Diastatic* malt contains the diastase enzyme used to promote more of the starches to be broken down into sugars that yeasts can use as food. Too much Diastatic malt will make your bread come out gummy inside. For flours that do not have barley malt already incorporated in them (i.e rye flours) a recommended amounts of diastatic malt powder is less than 2.0% of the total flour weight.